Time-independent background fields and angular dependence of spontaneously emitted light
I am trying to better understand spontaneous emission of an atom in vacuum and whether there can be favored directions for emission. I'm particularly interested in whether breaking the isotropy of space, such as through the choice of initial conditions, or through the presence of static background fields (this question), can induce favored or disfavored directions for emission.
Consider a hydrogen atom in an excited state in vacuum (i.e. not in a cavity). There is a background, time-independent electric and magnetic field produced by sources far away from the hydrogen atom, and these fields are slowly varying in space, if at all.
Does the presence of these static fields affect the angular distribution of the radiated light?

Hydrogen atom couples to electromagnetic space. This is how you get light emitted in the first place. So your question is along the lines of, if I change the energy of the system, will its behavior change? .... probably. Why not write out the Hamiltonian for the atom, and try applying electric field to it, and see how the solutions will change? Will depend a lot on the exact form of your electric/magnetic field (homogeneous or not), its strength, and the detail you will choose to include in your Hamiltonian

@Cryo Thanks for the comment. I think one of the points of confusion for me is that I've often heard that spontaneous emission can be understood via stimulated emission caused by the ground state quantum-mechanical electromagnetic field, and I am unsure how to do that. This question is one layer of complication on top, with a static field as well.

If you are after understanding, the best way is to solve some models of atom coupled to electromagnetic field. Starting with something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_Rabi_oscillation . The references section of the article contain books that provide more detailed treatment.

Electrostatic field treatment can then be added on top once you understand how the combined light-atom Hamiltonian depends on it.

I also don't quite understand your 'not in the cavity' setting. This will make it hard to quantize the electromagnetic field. You can find formulations which do not rely on cavities, but do you really need it?

@Cryo The motivation for no cavity was so that the fields are the only thing breaking the isotropy of space.

Spherical cavity with atom in the centre would be just as good. More to the point, as long as you allow all wave-vector/polarization combinations in your cavity (limited only by magnitude, not orientation of wave-vector), isotropy will be maintained
